# ASP.NET MVC How to convert application from ASP.NET Identity to Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, office365

I have an MVC application which currently uses Identity 2.0 for local sign on and Google SSO. I still need to use these, but I now need to add the ability to use Azure AD for an Organizational Account (Office 365) as well.

I have seen plenty of tutorials which show how to use Azure AD  for a new app, by selecting Organizational Account instead of Individual User Accounts.

Do I need to create a new empty project this way and then copy my whole code to this new app or is there a simpler way to do this?

I know about Auth0, but the cost of this is way too prohibitive for my needs right now.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you have implemented Identity 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading through [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Samples and Documentation](https://github.com/AzureADSamples), working through the sample [WebApp-OpenIdConnect-AspNet5](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIdConnect-AspNet5) and reviewing [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/).